# YouTube lifetime token for a server

Tags: youtube-api, google-developer-tools

I'm trying yo create a private application that manages a YouTube account all time, not different ones for clients, only one and the client has access to create a video streaming or other functions with YouTube API v3. Only I found how to the clients logging and manage their accounts but not only one channel all time.
How i can do that?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: How i can do that

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i beleave their question is how to authorize a user for all of their channels instead of each channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> YouTube lifetime token for a server

What you are refering to is something called service accounts.  Its designed for server to server interaction.  This type of autohrization is not supported by the YouTube API you need to use Oauth2.

> I'm trying yo create a private application that manages a YouTube account all time, not different ones for clients, only one and the client has access to create a video streaming or other functions with YouTube API v3.

You may have some issues here. You will need to create a project on Google developer console for your application and create Oauth2 credetinals.

In order to upload videos that are public your app will need to be verified.  Application verification takes time with youtube api. Make sure to apply for it early.

> Only I found how to the clients logging and manage their accounts but not only one channel all time.

YouTube authorization is channel based. Your users will need to be authorized for each one of their channels.  There is no way to authorize a single user to access  all of their channels in one go.  It has to be per channel.

Comment: Ouch, and if I store only one token with the respective refresh token for subapps?

Comment: if you only store one refresh token for the user it is for which ever channel they selected when they authorized your app.    For example i have six channels if i pick the second one then your app only has access to the second one.   For me to have access to the others your going to have to authorize me for each of the channels and keep track of refresh tokens for each of them.

Comment: Yes, but the acces is for many users with access to a youtube channel, for example a community channel that many users of my app with one button can create a stream event, and for other group other channel, but not one channel per users, I dont know if I had explained

Comment: You are going to have to work within the confines of this API.   It is not optimal but this is how it works.

Comment: I didn't really help i just explained how bad the auth for YouTube is 